# edit legend used in the power map in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I was wondering if we can customize the legend used in the power map in excel.
I wanted to change the color used by default in the heat map.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This document might be useful: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-color-of-a-data-series-in-3D-Maps-ca7e3d6d-fe4e-4680-a96a-66261b6a490d